# Ionic 5 - API request working on browser, not on emulated IOS

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

I have this Ionic 5/Capacitor app, which I'm making an API call to a local server from, that server running on docker at localhost:3000. When I test from the browser, the request is made fine. From Postman it requests fine, too. In my XCode logs the emulator, I see this

```
[error] - ERROR {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"http://localhost:3000/pins","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/pins: 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
```

The really interesting part, is that I'm running Fiddler to monitor the request as it's made. Fiddler gets a 200 as well, I can even see the response data. So, Fiddler sees the proper network call, but then my Ionic app gets that error. That makes me feel like it's an Ionic/Emulator/IOS problem, but I don't have enough familiarity with Ionic to know right off the bat what it is.

Here's the code responsible for making the request:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const request = this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/pins');

    this.refresh$.subscribe(
      (lastPos: { latitude?: any; longitude?: number }) => {
        request.subscribe(data => {
          if (data) {
            this.addMarkersToMap(data, lastPos);
          }
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

And the HTTPClient imported in the constructor is from Angular:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up having to use this package, doing a check on if I'm on mobile or not.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
const request = this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/pins', { observe: 'response', withCredentials: true });
```

**Solution 2 :** capacitor.config.json

```
"server": {
    "hostname": "localhost",  (maybe try precising the port number too)
}
```

**Solution 3 :** On your Express server (from https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/cors)

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

const allowedOrigins = [
  'capacitor://localhost',
  'ionic://localhost',
  'http://localhost',
  'http://localhost:8080',
  'http://localhost:8100'
];

// Reflect the origin if it's in the allowed list or not defined (cURL, Postman, etc.)
const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin) || !origin) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Origin not allowed by CORS'));
    }
  }
}

// Enable preflight requests for all routes
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));

app.get('/', cors(corsOptions), (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ message: 'This route is CORS-enabled for an allowed origin.' });
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: So I actually got this working by switching to the Ionic Native HTTP client. Would you recommend I switch back to the angular client and try this instead?

Comment: Yes, just try and tell me please. Ionic Native HTTP is good but you can't test it on browsers, and I met problems sending POST data with that plugin, I don't know the status now

Comment: I switched back to the Angular Client, still getting the same error with this as the code:

    const request = this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/pins', {
      observe: 'response',
      withCredentials: true
    });

    request.subscribe(_ => {
      this.addMarkersToMap(_);
    });

Comment: I'd love to get this solution working if you have any more thoughts, because now I'm getting a gray screen with the Ionic Native HTTP client. And i've already checked the API keys so I know that's not the issue.

Comment: It could also be related to CORS issues, did you enable CORS on your API? What runs it? For me,  I had to add ```quarkus.http.cors=true``` in my ```application.properties``` using Quarkus.

Comment: So I'm using a Node.js/Express server, here's what i'm doing for kinda hacking my CORS. `app.use(function(req, res, next) { res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'localhost:8100'); res.header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept' ); next(); });` I know it's not ideal, but it's a temporary fix until I install a package for it, and it works for the browser and Postman requests.

Comment: Ok, last thing to test and which definitely solved my problems yesterday with CORS was to add this in ```capacitor.config.json```: 

```"server":{"hostname":"mydomain"}```

So your domain is localhost. Without this, I was getting CORS errors, and with this, there wasn't problem

Comment: Added that, unfortunately still having issues :/. I honestly don't think it's a problem on the API side, I think it's with Ionic. Here's the network traffic from Fiddler, you can see that it's getting a `200` and returning the data as it should be. https://ibb.co/album/TvxM56. I also attached the error from the Ionic console.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for your answer, most important is that you solved your problem !

Comment: sorry, I may not have been clear enough. The problem is still happening. I was just saying that I think it’s on the Ionic side of things. I was saying the attached screenshots show that the network requests completes successfully but then breaks down when it reaches the Ionic app. You can see the error and network calls on the screenshots I linked in the previous comment.

Comment: I've edited my post, did you try having a look at https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/cors
There's a specific solution for Express servers, I put it on my post.